# Java: Scanner reads integer, but doesn't use it in while/for loop

Tags: java, algorithm, java.util.scanner

My book I'm learning with uses another libary for reading Inputs so it can't help me....

I can't see where my mistake is. The algorithm:

1. Read the value of n
2. Set the value of i to 3
3. Follow the steps

Iterate

```
While i < 2*n

       i+1

       Write 1/(2*i+1) to the console.
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aufgabe420 {
public static void main (String[] args) {
int i, n; 

    System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("n ="+n);
    System.out.println("The while-loop starts!");
    i = 3;
    while (i < 2*n){
        i += 1;
        System.out.println(1/(2*i+1));
    }

        System.out.println("now with for-loop");    

    for (i = 3; i < (2*n); i+=1) {
        System.out.println(1/(2*i+1));
    }


    }
}
```

But trying it, it results in:
Please enter a number!
5

n =5
The while-loop starts!
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

now with for-loop
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

What's wrong with that code? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1/(2*i+1)` will result in 0 for any positive `i`, since 1 < (2*i+1) and int division can't result in fractions.

change

```
System.out.println(1/(2*i+1));
```

to

```
System.out.println(1.0/(2*i+1));
```

You want to perform floating point division, not int division.

Comment: Well. Sometimes it's the easiest things what happens to make it difficult.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
System.out.println(1/(2*i+1));
```

has the problem that it performs an integer division. And 1 divided by any value greater than 1 will always be 0. Solution: one of the operands must be a float for the result to be float, e.g. like this:

```
System.out.println(1.0/(2*i+1));
```

or do this:

```
System.out.println(1/(float)(2*i+1));
```